# Drag and drop does not work with NSStatusItem from OSX Dock's Download Stack

Tags: objective-c, macos, drag-and-drop, osx-yosemite, dock

I am trying to get the file from OSX Dock's `Download Stack`. When i drag a file `draggingEntered` and `draggingExited` is called. But neither `performDragOperation` nor `concludeDragOperation` is called.

When i drop file from finder, it works fine.

I registered types for my dragview as follow

```
[_dragView registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSFilenamesPboardType, NSTIFFPboardType, NSStringPboardType, @"local-file-url", @"public.file-url", nil]];
```

## Update

---

Problem is it does accept files from `Download Stack` if that view is in some window. But when i setup that view to `NSStatusItem` it never calls `performDragOperation`.

Comment: Did you implement the other methods of `NSDraggingDestination`?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Yes i have, it works perfectly fine when i drop a file form finder.

Comment: Ah, it only does not work when dragging from the download stack?

Comment: Yeah it does not work from download stack.

Answer (score 0):

In the official [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSDraggingDestination_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSDraggingDestination/prepareForDragOperation:), it is said:

> For this method to be invoked, the previous prepareForDragOperation: message must have returned YES

Is that the case in your code?

Comment: `prepareForDragOperation` is implemented and always return `YES`. Read the comments in question. It does not work in case of `Download Stack'. From finder its working fine.